# Skew Binary Trees

Tags: tree, binary-tree, skew

1) What is meant by the term unbalanced binary tree and how we can write an algorithm to test it?

2) I have a problem which asks to write a function to test the depth of a binary tree. I think this would work but not sure....:

```
function getDepth(Node n){
    if(node == null){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 + Math.max(getDepth(node.left), getDepth(node.right));
}
getDepth(root);
```

Can anyone give me pointers...

Comment: It seems to be that the term "Skew Binary Tree" is actually a combination of two different concepts. Please rephrase what you are looking for.

Comment: There are still many definitions for unbalencedness - look for the wikipedia article on AVL trees and Red-Black trees, for example.

Answer (score 0):

<s>1) Skew binary tree is not a 100% widespread common term (even Google gets confused). Search your lecture notes or book to see what they mean with it.</s>

1. To test is a tree has as many leves as nodes, you could just use the function you already have that counts levels and another function to count the number of nodes.

   However, you should be abe to make another, more efficient, algorithm that terminates earlier if if finds that the number of nodes cannot be the same as the number of levels.
2. The depth function is correct. After all, isn't this taken straight from the definition of tree depth?

   (the only possible nitpick is the depth(null) = 1. Just be sure you don't need depth(null) = 0 instead)

Comment: skew binary tree is where the tree is as deep as possible - i.e. it has as many nodes as levels (assume base level = 1)

Answer (score 0):

Skewed Binary tree is the tree which has only one type of sub trees. If a tree has only left sub trees then it is left skewed tree and vice versa.